# ros-controls content

Tags: ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am currently having a look at metapackage ros-controls. There are 5 packages in there:

- ros_control
- ros_controllers
- control_msgs
- realtime_tools
- control_toolbox

The reason of being of the first 2 is clearly stated [here](https://github.com/ros-controls). Thanks to a bit of digging I could figure out that the 3rd one (control_msgs) contains the definition of control-specific messages. Now I am not too sure what the last 2 packages are useful for (**realtime_tools** & **control_toolbox**).

Anyone knows a bit more on the matter?

Thanks,

Antoine

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191194/ros-controls-content/) by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 955 on 2014-08-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First thing I always do is just check out the wiki pages, which seem to -- fortunately -- contain quite some information:

- [realtime_tools](http://wiki.ros.org/realtime_tools):

> Contains a set of tools that can be used from a hard realtime thread, without breaking the realtime behavior. The tools currently only provides the realtime publisher, which makes it possible to publish messages to a ROS topic from a realtime thread. We plan to add a basic implementation of a realtime buffer, to make it possible to get data from a (non-realtime) topic callback into the realtime loop. Once the lockfree buffer is created, the realtime publisher will start using it, which will result in major API changes for the realtime publisher (removal of all lock methods).

- [control_toolbox](http://wiki.ros.org/control_toolbox)

> This package contains several C++ classes useful in writing controllers, and so the main documentation can be found on the [control_toolbox doxygen page](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/control_toolbox/html/).

All accessible from the meta-package page: [ros_control](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_control).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on 2014-08-26**:
Thanks gvdhoorn, I thought there was doc only for the meta-package in the wiki, had not realized there was also doc for all sub-packages... This opens doors ;)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-08-26**:
:). Glad to have helped.